# Jenkins - Unable to access to repository

Tags: java, linux, svn, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins to download code from SVN repository and to prepare builds.
Jenkins is on one linux machine - version 1.651.1
Subversion Plug-in 2.5.7
SVN repository is set on another linux machine.

A set repository URL to eg: http://abcsvn/svn/project/branches/branch_a/HEAD/
Unfortunately I get: 'Unable to access to repository' message from Jenkins.

I also tried to put IP instead of abcsvn. 
From terminal on linux machine where the Jenkins is installed I can ping IP successfully.

What may be the reason of that kind of problem? The URL is correct, because I paste that in Chrome on my machine and it worked correctly.

I also installed Jenkins on my computer with Windows. I set the same parameters and I am still not able to connect to svn repo. In Eclipse I don't have any problem to commit and checkout from svn repo.

If you need any more information to diagnose this problem I will try to complete this post.

Comment: Please provide output from /var/log/jenkins.log

Comment: The beginning of the log added in next post

Comment: Started by user anonymous Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestMD/workspace Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestMD/workspace Cleaning local Directory. Checking out http://abcsvn/svn/project/branches/branch_a/HEAD at revision '2016-08-11T09:49:15.986 +0200' ERROR: Failed to check out http://abc/svn/project/branches/branch org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided' at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62

Answer (score 2):

Exception says that you have not provided credentials of your svn repository. In newer version of svn we can provide this credential while we configure workspace. In your version it can be provided from manage Jenkins menu.

Comment: I provided login and password the same as I use to connect to svn repo via Eclipse -> it doesn't work :(

Comment: To find the reason of such problems look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50254600/5162026